# How to implement random walks with restarts in python

Tags: python, networkx, igraph

I have the following graph that I created using `networkx`.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from(["John", "Mary", "Jill", "Todd",
                  "iPhone5", "Kindle Fire", "Fitbit Flex Wireless", "Harry Potter", "Hobbit"])

G.add_edges_from([
    ("John", "iPhone5"),
    ("John", "Kindle Fire"),
    ("Mary", "iPhone5"),
    ("Mary", "Kindle Fire"),
    ("Mary", "Fitbit Flex Wireless"),
    ("Jill", "iPhone5"),
    ("Jill", "Kindle Fire"),
    ("Jill", "Fitbit Flex Wireless"),
    ("Todd", "Fitbit Flex Wireless"),
    ("Todd", "Harry Potter"),
    ("Todd", "Hobbit"),
])
```

Now, I want to perform `random walk with restarts` to identify the most similar users to `John`. I searched the documentation in `networkx` and I could not find an implementation of it in `networkx`.

Please let me know if there is python library/code for `random walk with restarts` to do this.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

### EDIT

If my existing network is weighted like below, would I still calculate the random walks with restarts as following: `nx.pagerank_numpy(G, personalization={"John": 1})`?

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from(["John", "Mary", "Jill", "Todd",
                  "iPhone5", "Kindle Fire", "Fitbit Flex Wireless", "Harry Potter", "Hobbit"])

G.add_weighted_edges_from([
    ("John", "iPhone5", 0.1),
    ("John", "Kindle Fire", 0.2),
    ("Mary", "iPhone5", 0.3),
    ("Mary", "Kindle Fire", 0.4),
    ("Mary", "Fitbit Flex Wireless", 0.5),
    ("Jill", "iPhone5", 0.9),
    ("Jill", "Kindle Fire", 0.1),
    ("Jill", "Fitbit Flex Wireless", 0.1),
    ("Todd", "Fitbit Flex Wireless", 0.1),
    ("Todd", "Harry Potter", 0.1),
    ("Todd", "Hobbit", 0.1),
])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personalised PageRank—[implemented in networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank_numpy.html#networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank_numpy)—is essentially a random walk with restarts if the personalisation vector has 1 for the starting node and 0 everywhere else.

The following code

```py
nx.pagerank_numpy(G, personalization={"John": 1})
```

then yields a dictionary with probabilities of ending up in each node

```
{'John': 0.24958826532666656,
 'Mary': 0.1229452674202248,
 'Jill': 0.12294526742022475,
 'Todd': 0.04506174037342413,
 'iPhone5': 0.17574399763529416,
 'Kindle Fire': 0.17574399763529416,
 'Fitbit Flex Wireless': 0.08243647797726429,
 'Harry Potter': 0.012767493105803515,
 'Hobbit': 0.012767493105803515}
```

From this dictionary, you can select the user with highest probability.

For a **weighted graph**, the `pagerank_numpy` method has a `weight` argument where you can set an edges data key to be used. When adding edges with [`add_weighted_edges_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_weighted_edges_from.html?highlight=add_weighted_edges_from#networkx.Graph.add_weighted_edges_from) this data key is called `"weight"` and so the code becomes as follows.

```py
nx.pagerank_numpy(G, personalization={"John": 1}, weight="weight")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wonderful answer. I did not know that personalised pagerank is the random walk with restarts in networkx. Do you have any supporting evidence that I can cite in this regard? Thank you :)

Comment: Most papers on efficient PageRank computation or its applications mention this. Here's [one](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1989323.1989425), [two](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?type=printable&id=10.1371/journal.pone.0213857), [three](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4053087) examples.

Comment: Thank you. I found the papers that you have linked very useful. I have one last question that I thought would be great to get your feedback on. Please see the "EDIT:" section of my updated question. More specifically, I want to know if I would calculate the random walk wit restarts the same way with weighted networks? Thank you :)

Comment: There is a `weight` argument—I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very useful. Thank you :)

Comment: I thought that you may have some interesting suggestions for this questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61830490/what-are-other-methods-in-networkx-similar-to-personalised-pagerank Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you :)

Comment: @PidgeyUsedGust in this case, the closest to John is john and then some items (instead of users) is that how we are supposed to interpret these results? so the user other than john close to john is Mary. Is that correct? and the closest item to John is Iphone.